# Parametric Plots [continuous and discrete]: --showing parameter increase for multiple values of another parameter

Tags: graphics, version-9

In my problem, I am effectively plotting a parametric function that depends also on an outside parameter, e.g., the real/imaginary parts of

```
ff[tt_, param_] := (tt + I * param)^2
```

I plot one parametric plot in `tt` for each of several values of `param`, i.e., if I let `param` vary in {1, 2, 3}, and `tt` vary in [-3, 4], I get

[image: standard Parametric Plot with Multiple Plots]

In addition, one of the more complicated functions I am using is hard to compute, so in that case, I use a medium-fine grid of `tt` and use `ListPlot` or `Graphics` primitives instead of `ParametricPlot`.  I.e., I get something like this:

[image: standard ListPlot with multiple plots]

The main issue is that I want to give the reader some sense of the direction in which `tt` is increasing, but I cannot use color as that is already being used to distinguish the different values of `param`.  I could just use text labels, but for my diagrams, that would tend to clutter the picture if they were typed with any frequency.  Therefore, I would prefer to use another method.

---

### Main Question

Short of adding text labels to the picture, how can I visually display the direction of increase in the parameter `tt` in a multiple-graph plot?  I am interested in the answer for both `ParametricPlot` and a `ListPlot` or other discrete plot that mimics it.

---

I will put my attempted solutions thus far as answers.  One works for both types of plots, but the other only works for a discrete plot.

**Note:  I am using Mathematica 9.0.1, so the `ParametricPlot`/`PlotLegends` disagreement, as noted in [ParametricPlot and PlotLegends don't seem to cooperate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21104/parametricplot-and-plotlegends-dont-seem-to-cooperate), applies.

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48882/placing-many-arrowheads-on-curves

Answer (score 1):

## A better solution for Discrete Plots

We can use  `Point` instead of `ListPlot`, and then vary the size as `t` or `tt` varies.

We compute the sizes as follows:

```
unitize[t_, tMin_, tMax_] := (t - tMin)/(tMax - tMin)
sizeBase[u_, sizeMin_, sizeMax_] := sizeMin + (sizeMax - sizeMin)*u
sizer[{t_, tMin_, tMax_}, {sizeMin_, sizeMax_, dir_}] := 
Piecewise[{{sizeBase[unitize[t, tMin, tMax], sizeMin, sizeMax], dir == "incr"}, 
       {sizeBase[1 - unitize[t, tMin, tMax], sizeMin, sizeMax], dir == "decr"}}]
```

`unitize` just moves `[tMin, tMax]` to `[0, 1]`, `sizeBase` moves that to the interval of sizes.  `sizer` modifies `sizeBase` to let the user decide whether the circles should increase or decrease as the parameter `tt` increases.  I pass all the size arguments to the user since they will depend on the size of the plot.

We now recall our function and get a list for a fixed `param` value.  It *should* automatically find the biggest/smallest `t` value.

```
Parts[z_] := {Re[z], Im[z]}
ff[tt_, param_] := (tt + I * param)^2 ;
pointListAlt[ttList_,  {param_, col_}, {sizeMin_, sizeMax_, dir_}] := 
 Table[{PointSize[sizer[{ttList[[j]], Sort[ttList][[1]], Sort[ttList[[Length[ttList]]]}, 
 {sizeMin, sizeMax, dir}]], col, Point[Parts[ff[ttList[[j]], param]]]}, {j, 1, Length[ttList]}]
```

Now all we need to do is the final plotting wrapper, including labels.

```
paramLabel[paramList_List] := 
  Table[Row[{"param = ", paramList[[j]]}], {j, 1, Length[paramList]}]
SeveralListPlotsVarySize[tFullList_, paramList_, {sizeMin_, sizeMax_, dir_}] := 
Legended[Graphics[
Table[pointListAlt[tFullList, {paramList[[j]], ColorData[1][j]}, {sizeMin, sizeMax, 
  dir}],
  {j, 1, Length[paramList]}], Axes -> True], 
{Placed[ PointLegend[(ColorData[1][#]) & /@ #, 
   paramLabel[paramList][[#]]] & @ Range @ Length[paramList],  Right]}]
```

We set the list of `t` values as in my other answer:

```
 (*Construct the t list*)
 tSmall = -3; tLarge = 4 ; dt = 1/10; numTs = Floor[(tLarge - tSmall)/dt] + 1; 
 dt = (tLarge - tSmall)/(numTs - 1);
 tList = Table[tSmall + (j - 1)* dt, {j, 1, numTs}];
```

Then plugging in

```
SeveralListPlotsVarySize[tList, {1, 2, 3}, {0.01, 0.05, "incr"}]
```

yields

[image: parametric plot with increasing point size]

and plugging in

```
SeveralListPlotsVarySize[tList, {1, 2, 3}, {0.01, 0.05, "decr"}]
```

yields

[image: parametric plot with decreasing point size]

That looks reasonably good.

Answer (score 0):

### A simple, not so good solution.

We use special colors (the primary colors work well) to distinguish the start and endpoints.

*ParametricPlot version*

Again, thanks to the answers to [ParametricPlot and PlotLegends don't seem to cooperate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21104/parametricplot-and-plotlegends-dont-seem-to-cooperate) and [How to simulate Placed in workaround for PlotLegends ParametricPlot bug?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72044/how-to-simulate-placed-in-workaround-for-plotlegends-parametricplot-bug/72045#72045) for pointing me in the right fixes for 9.0.1.

```
Parts[z_] := {Re[z], Im[z]};
ff[tt_, param_] := (tt + I * param)^2 ;
(*Need an implicit wrapper for the workaround; 
need an explicit wrapper to evaluate the endpoints*)
ffImplicit[paramList_List] := Transpose[Parts[ff[t, paramList]]]
ffExplicit[tt_, paramList_List] := Transpose[Parts[ff[tt, paramList]]]
(*Commands to plot a t-value with all corresponding parameter values*)
pointListU[tHere_,  paramList_List, size_, colorOption_] := 
 Table[{{PointSize[size], colorOption, Point@#}} &@
   ffExplicit[tHere,  paramList][[j]], {j, 1, Length[paramList]}]
pointCollectU[tList_List,  paramList_List, size_, 
  colorOptionList_List] := 
 Table[pointListUnlabeled[tList[[j]],  paramList, size, 
   colorOptionList[[j]]], {j, 1, Length[tList]}]
(*Construct Labels*)
tLabel[ttList_] := 
Table[Row[{"t = ", ttList[[j]]}], {j, 1, Length[ttList]}];
paramLabel[paramList_List] := 
 Table[Row[{"param = ", paramList[[j]]}], {j, 1, Length[paramList]}]
(*Plotting Command*)
SeveralPlotsWithEndpointsD[tList_List, paramList_List , 
  pointColorList_List, legendLoc_] := 
 With[{localFuncList = ffImplicit[ paramList], 
   localLabels = paramLabel[paramList]}, 
  With[{n = Length@localFuncList, m = Length[tList]}, 
   Legended[
    ParametricPlot[localFuncList, {t, tList[[1]], tList[[m]]}, 
     ImageSize -> Large, PlotRangePadding -> {3, 2}, 
     Epilog -> {pointCollectU[tList,  paramList, .01, 
        pointColorList]}], {Placed[
      LineLegend[(ColorData[1][#]) & /@ #, localLabels[[#]]] & @ 
       Range @ n, {Right, Bottom}], 
     Placed[PointLegend[pointColorList, tLabel[tList]], legendLoc]}]]]
```

Evaluating with

```
SeveralPlotsWithEndpointsD[{-3, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {Black, Red}, {Right, 
Bottom}]
```

gives

[image: Above with brightly covered endpoints, parametric case]

O.K., it does the job, but it doesn't look great.

*ListPlot version*

Start by taking everything from the previous version above `(*PlottingCommand*)`, though you can omit the wrappers `ffImplicit` and `ffExplicit`.

```
 (*Primary Plotting Command*)
SeveralListPlotsB[tFullList_, tShortList_, paramList_, 
  shortColorList_] := 
 Legended[ListPlot[
    Table[Parts[ff[t, p]], {p, paramList}, {t, tFullList}], 
   Epilog -> {pointCollectU[tShortList, ParamList, 0.03, 
       shortColorList]}], {Placed[
   PointLegend[(ColorData[1][#]) & /@ #, 
     paramLabel[paramList][[#]]] & @ Range @ Length[paramList], 
    Right], Placed[PointLegend[shortColorList, tLabel[tShortList]], 
    Right]}]
```

Evaluating with

```
(*Construct the t list*)
tSmall = -3; tLarge = 4 ; dt = 1/10; numTs = 
 Floor[(tLarge - tSmall)/dt] + 1; 
dt = (tLarge - tSmall)/(numTs - 1);
tList = Table[tSmall + (j - 1)* dt, {j, 1, numTs}];
SeveralListPlotsB[tList, {-3, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {Black, Red}]
```

which yields

[image: ListPlot with extra Graphics Points]

Again, it's OK.  It avoids putting text in on top of other text, but that's its only advantage.